# PyQT5 Signals connect method not actually binding the method

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am creating a python application.

Link to ui.py and app.py: https://gist.github.com/tbhaxor/f68387d49bc59b2bdd025512c17a2534

**ui.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'recent.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.0
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        MainWindow.setEnabled(True)
        MainWindow.resize(975, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(975, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(975, 600))
        MainWindow.setMouseTracking(False)
        MainWindow.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        MainWindow.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-3, 0, 981, 611))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.tabWidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.tabWidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.t_msngr = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.t_msngr.setObjectName("t_msngr")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.t_msngr)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 540, 510, 17))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.t_msngr)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(13, 10, 951, 194))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.txt_recent_profiles = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.widget)
        self.txt_recent_profiles.setReadOnly(True)
        self.txt_recent_profiles.setObjectName("txt_recent_profiles")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.txt_recent_profiles)
        self.widget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.t_msngr)
        self.widget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(581, 530, 381, 31))
        self.widget1.setObjectName("widget1")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget1)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.btn_fetch = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget1)
        self.btn_fetch.setObjectName("btn_fetch")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_fetch)
        self.btn_save_template = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget1)
        self.btn_save_template.setObjectName("btn_save_template")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_save_template)
        self.btn_send_all = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.widget1)
        self.btn_send_all.setObjectName("btn_send_all")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.btn_send_all)
        self.widget2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.t_msngr)
        self.widget2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 220, 841, 30))
        self.widget2.setObjectName("widget2")
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget2)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.search_predicate = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.widget2)
        self.search_predicate.setObjectName("search_predicate")
        self.search_predicate.addItem("")
        self.search_predicate.addItem("")
        self.search_predicate.addItem("")
        self.search_predicate.addItem("")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.search_predicate)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(150, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.searchee = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget2)
        self.searchee.setObjectName("searchee")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.searchee)
        self.search_limit = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget2)
        self.search_limit.setObjectName("search_limit")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.search_limit)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.widget3 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.t_msngr)
        self.widget3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 270, 950, 241))
        self.widget3.setObjectName("widget3")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget3)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget3)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.txt_template = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.widget3)
        self.txt_template.setReadOnly(True)
        self.txt_template.setObjectName("txt_template")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.txt_template)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.t_msngr, "")
        self.t_stngs = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.t_stngs.setObjectName("t_stngs")
        self.btn_save_settings = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.t_stngs)
        self.btn_save_settings.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(880, 540, 83, 25))
        self.btn_save_settings.setObjectName("btn_save_settings")
        self.widget4 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.t_stngs)
        self.widget4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 960, 81))
        self.widget4.setObjectName("widget4")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget4)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget4)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_5)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.txt_email = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget4)
        self.txt_email.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.txt_email.setObjectName("txt_email")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.txt_email)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget4)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_6)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(72, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Maximum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.txt_passwd = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget4)
        self.txt_passwd.setFrame(True)
        self.txt_passwd.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.PasswordEchoOnEdit)
        self.txt_passwd.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.txt_passwd.setObjectName("txt_passwd")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.txt_passwd)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        self.widget5 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.t_stngs)
        self.widget5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 140, 960, 27))
        self.widget5.setObjectName("widget5")
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget5)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget5)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label_7)
        self.txt_api_key = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.widget5)
        self.txt_api_key.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.txt_api_key.setObjectName("txt_api_key")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.txt_api_key)
        self.widget6 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.t_stngs)
        self.widget6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 185, 341, 61))
        self.widget6.setObjectName("widget6")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget6)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_9 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_9.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_9")
        self.label_8 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget6)
        self.label_8.setObjectName("label_8")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.label_8)
        self.lbl_plan_type = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget6)
        self.lbl_plan_type.setText("")
        self.lbl_plan_type.setObjectName("lbl_plan_type")
        self.horizontalLayout_9.addWidget(self.lbl_plan_type)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_9)
        self.horizontalLayout_10 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_10.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_10")
        self.label_9 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget6)
        self.label_9.setObjectName("label_9")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.label_9)
        self.lbl_expiry = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget6)
        self.lbl_expiry.setText("")
        self.lbl_expiry.setObjectName("lbl_expiry")
        self.horizontalLayout_10.addWidget(self.lbl_expiry)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_10)
        self.widget7 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.t_stngs)
        self.widget7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 220, 341, 28))
        self.widget7.setObjectName("widget7")
        self.horizontalLayout_11 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.widget7)
        self.horizontalLayout_11.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_11.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_11")
        self.label_10 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget7)
        self.label_10.setObjectName("label_10")
        self.horizontalLayout_11.addWidget(self.label_10)
        self.delay = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.widget7)
        self.delay.setMinimum(10)
        self.delay.setMaximum(20)
        self.delay.setObjectName("delay")
        self.horizontalLayout_11.addWidget(self.delay)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.t_stngs, "")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Linkedin Recent Connection Messenger"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p>Use <span style=\" font-style:italic;\">{{name}}</span> for dynamic naming</p></body></html>"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Recent Profiles"))
        self.btn_fetch.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Fetch"))
        self.btn_save_template.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save Template"))
        self.btn_send_all.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Send To All"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search By"))
        self.search_predicate.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Days"))
        self.search_predicate.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Weeks"))
        self.search_predicate.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Months"))
        self.search_predicate.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Years"))
        self.searchee.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Search Limit"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Template"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.t_msngr), _translate("MainWindow", "Messenger"))
        self.btn_save_settings.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save All"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Email Address"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Password"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "API Key"))
        self.label_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Plan Type"))
        self.label_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Expiry Date"))
        self.label_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delay"))
        self.delay.setSuffix(_translate("MainWindow", " secs"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.t_stngs), _translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))
```

**app.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from ui import Ui_MainWindow
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import traceback
import pickle as pkl
from pathlib import Path
from typing import List, Dict, Union


class Application(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,
                 window: QtWidgets.QMainWindow,
                 driver: WebDriver = None):
        self.parent = window
        self.driver = driver
        self.setupUi(window)
        self.retranslateUi(window)

        qtRectangle = window.frameGeometry()
        centerPoint = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        window.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())
        self.__makeHandlers()

        self.file = os.path.join(Path.home(), "_linkedin.db")
        self.db: Dict[str, str] = {
            "api": "",
            "email": "",
            "password": "",
            "sent": [],
            "delay": 10,
            "template": ""
        }
        self.search_limit.valueChanged.connect(print)
        pass

    def __makeHandlers(self):
        self.search_limit.valueChanged.connect(print)
        pass

    def handle_fetch(self):
        pass

    def __login(self):
        driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/login")
        # /html/body/div[1]/main/div/form/div[1]/input
        # /html/body/div[1]/main/div/form/div[2]/input
        # /html/body/div[1]/main/div/form/div[4]/button
        pass

    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    try:
        opts = Options()
        opts.headless = os.environ.get("PYDBG", "0") != "1"
        driver: WebDriver = WebDriver(options=opts)
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Application(MainWindow)
        ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.show()
        app.exec_()
        pass
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
        pass
    finally:
        driver.quit()
        pass
```

When i am trying to connect `search_limit` (spinbox) with `print` function on event `valueChanged` at [line 40 in app.py](https://gist.github.com/tbhaxor/f68387d49bc59b2bdd025512c17a2534#file-app-py-L40), it's neither connecting the print function nor returning any error at [line 72 in app.py](https://gist.github.com/tbhaxor/f68387d49bc59b2bdd025512c17a2534#file-app-py-L72)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is trivial: By executing the setupUi method you are creating the internal widgets, what happens if setupUi is run a second time? Well, the old widgets are removed and new ones are created. In your case you have called setupUi first in the constructor of Application and you have called it again after `ui = Application(MainWindow)`, on the first call you make the connection and then delete it so the connection was broken. The solution: Just call setupUi once. It is also not necessary to call retranslateUi since setupUi already does.

```
class Application(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,
                 window: QtWidgets.QMainWindow,
                 driver: WebDriver = None):
        self.parent = window
        self.driver = driver
        self.setupUi(window)
        # self.retranslateUi(window) # remove this line

        qtRectangle = window.frameGeometry()
        # ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    try:
        opts = Options()
        opts.headless = os.environ.get("PYDBG", "0") != "1"
        driver: WebDriver = WebDriver(options=opts)
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        ui = Application(MainWindow)
        # ui.setupUi(MainWindow) # remove this line
        MainWindow.show()
        app.exec_()
    except Exception:
        print(traceback.format_exc())
    finally:
        driver.quit()
```